# I want to create a batch file which would ask for a file name and save it on a FTP folder

Tags: batch-file

I checked lost of articles on this website but could not combine them to get the result. I am new to Batch. I've been working on VB all these years. The problem is that I don't have VB in my office. I need to do this using batch. Please help me out.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Please rephrase this question? Make an ordered list of what should happen running this batch file.

Comment: what means ftp folder?do you have server name,user,pass ?

Comment: sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I have FTP address. FTP username. FTP password. I want a Batch file to have following options: (1) ask for a filename and save that filename.txt in a folder on FTP. (2) get the list of files in that folder on FTP and read any one of them.

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

```
@echo off
set "ftp_server=localhost"
set "user=ftptest"
set "password=123
set "ftp_folder=."
set /p "file_to_upload=choose file"

(
echo open %ftp_server%
echo %user%
echo %password%
echo cd %ftp_folder%
echo put %file_to_upload%
echo ls
) >ftp.script
ftp -i -s:ftp.script > output.txt
```

to choose and download:

```
@echo off
set "ftp_server=localhost"
set "user=ftptest"
set "password=123
set "ftp_folder=."
set /p "file_to_upload=choose file"

(
echo open %ftp_server%
echo %user%
echo %password%
echo ls "%ftp_folder%" ls.out
) >ftp.script1
ftp -i -s:ftp.script1 > output.txt

echo files to choose:
type ls.out

set /p "file_d=choose file to download:"
find "%file_d%" "ls.out" || >nul 2>&1(
    echo file not in the list
    exit /b 1
) 

(
echo open %ftp_server%
echo %user%
echo %password%
echo %file_d% 
) >ftp.script2

ftp -i -s:ftp.script2 >> output.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. set /p "file_to_upload=choose file" is where I am in need of some modifications. The batch that i want should have a specified fixed path of the folder and should prompt the user to input the name of the file. Result should be: i open the batch. it should ask me a file name to upload. I should enter like David.txt. The path of this file should be fixed on the computer like "c:\project\" Then the program will save the file c:\project\david.txt to a fixed folder on FTP. Please help.

Comment: great !! I figured it out. Just 1 error. I don't want the "ftp.script" or "output.txt" to be saved. Can the batch delete them after the successful run?

Comment: @newusercitrix yes they can.check DEL command. At the moment im AFK and cant help you much from my phone.But you are done if you can accept the answer :-)

Comment: uploading completed !! Please help me with a batch which can list the files from a specified folder on FTP and then ask for a file name and download that file only.

Comment: @newusercitrix just need to return to my pc